# JavaScript - disable page refresh on mobile device

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am trying to disable page refresh on mobile device by touch scroll event.
Searching online, I have found the following approach:

```
/*
w = flag determining if pageYOffset was 0 before trying scroll below it
h = last pageYOffset
*/
function disablePageRefreshFacility() {
    let w,h=0;
    document.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e) {
        if(e.touches.length!=1) return;
        h=e.touches[0].clientY; w=window.pageYOffset===0;

        // testLabel is DOM element just to show the current pageYOffset - for test     
        testLabel.innerHTML=window.pageYOffset;
    },false);
    document.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e) {
        let y=e.touches[0].clientY,d=y-h; h=y;
        if(w) { w=0; if(d>0) return e.preventDefault(); }
        if(window.pageYOffset===0&&d>0) return e.preventDefault();
    },false);
}
```

The page have only testLabel DIV and document.body.style.height="60000px" for test.

**The issue:**

- Testing the value of pageYOffset When the page is NOT zoomed, the pageYOffset get scroll value as per the page.
- Testing the value of pageYOffset when page IS zoomed, the value remains 0 till certain scroll point which currently **I have no idea how to detect.**
- Removing the `document.body.style.height="60000px"` line making the body not scrollable, then, when zoomed, scrolling the page does NOT updating the value of pageYOffset.

**Notes:**

1. Tested on Android browser
2. Using pure JS, no framework.
3. Test is on touchstart - so I get the pageYOffset value AFTER last scroll.

## Problem summary

1. The touchmove event hasn't fired when the page is zoomed, unless I started the "real" scroll out of the initial innerHeight (before zoom, perhaps).
2. The problem of page refresh has **NOT been solved**

Any solution for pageYOffset (or alternative way) can help a lot solving the page refresh issue.
Any alternative can really help, though I wonder why touchmove event hasn't fired, though the page been "scrolled" (zoomed though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body {               
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
}
```

Comment: Tried, but yet not working, I can still do page refresh... - can see running example in www.efsdk.com/test/pg_rf.htm - Tested on Android browser...

Comment: try to change on `position: fixed;`

Comment: Yet not works, see this page - www.efsdk.com/test/pg_rf2.htm

Comment: Then it should works if you apply the same to the `html` object. Changed the code above.

Comment: Tried, still not working:( See this page - www.efsdk.com/test/pg_rf3.htm

Comment: i found the way how do it correctly check this out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231088/discussion-between-xerix-and-fakt309).